# Create a Pojo that has a Pojo inside?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-room, entity-relationship

So i am developing a chat application. There is a part in which i am interested on retrieving 3 entities from the Database but in once. There is a serverDto entity and accountDto entity. Every server has many accounts and there is a field in accounts called active, and if active = 1 means that is my account.
I have created a POJO named ServerAccount like below

```
class ServerAccount {
    @Embedded
    var accountDto: AccountDto? = null

    // Server and Account have same column "serverId"
    @Relation(parentColumn = "serverId", entityColumn = "serverId")
    var rUserDto: RUserDto? = null
}
```

So since i have that i want every time i open the chatRoomActivity to have the Contact and the ServerAccount at once, but i want them seperated entities and not a big object with many fields. What i mean is something like below

```
class ContactServerAccount {
    @Embedded
    var contact: AccountDto? = null

    @Embedded
    var account: AccountDto? = null

    @Embedded
    var server: ServerDto? = null


////////////////////////////////////
    // OR something like that //
////////////////////////////////////


    @Embedded
    var serverAccount: ServerAccount = null

    @Relation
    var contact: AccountDto = null

}
```

How can i do that with given a serverId which gives me the serverAccount and the contactId which gives me the contact..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you could use three methods, full embedding (all three tables embedded), hierarchial embedding (contact + ServerAccount) or limited Embedding (without @Relates)

I believe that the 3rd meets your minimalist/reduced data so something similar to :-

```
class ContactServerAccountLimited {

    var serverId: Long = 0 /* or Long? = null */
    var accountId: Long = 0

    @Embedded
    var contact: Contact = Contact()
}
```

used along with :-

```
@Query("SELECT serverId,accountId,contact.* FROM server JOIN account ON accountServerId = serverId JOIN contact ON contactServerId = serverId WHERE active = :active")
fun getContactServerAccountLimited(active :Boolean) :List<ContactServerAccountLimited>
```

---

## Example

The Entities used :-

```
@Entity(tableName = "server")
class Server {

    @PrimaryKey
    var serverId: Long? = null;
    var servername: String? = null;

    constructor()

    @Ignore
    constructor(name: String) {
        serverId = null
        servername = name
    }
}

@Entity(
    tableName = "account",
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Server::class,
            parentColumns = ["serverId"],
            childColumns = ["accountServerId"])
    ]
)
class Account {

    @PrimaryKey
    var accountId: Long? = null

    var accountServerId: Long? = null
    var accountName: String? = null
    var active: Boolean = false

    constructor()

    @Ignore
    constructor(accountName: String, accountServerId: Long) {
        this.accountName = accountName
        this.accountServerId = accountServerId
        this.active = false
    }
}

@Entity(
    tableName = "contact",
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Server::class,
            parentColumns = ["serverId"],
            childColumns = ["contactServerId"]
        )
    ]
)
class Contact {

    @PrimaryKey
    var contactId: Long? = null
    var contactServerId: Long? = null
    var contactName: String? = null

    constructor()

    @Ignore
    constructor(name: String, serverId: Long) {
        contactId = null
        contactName = name
        contactServerId = serverId
    }
}
```

The POJO's :-

```
class ContactServerAccount  {

    @Embedded
    var serverAccount: ServerAccount? = ServerAccount()
    @Relation(entity = Contact::class,parentColumn = "serverId",entityColumn = "contactServerId")
    var contact: Contact = Contact()
}

class ContactServerAccountLimited {

    var serverId: Long = 0
    var accountId: Long = 0

    @Embedded
    var contact: Contact = Contact()
}
```

The Dao :-

```
@Dao
interface AllDao {

    @Insert
    fun insertServer(server: Server): Long

    @Insert
    fun insertAccount(account: Account): Long

    @Insert
    fun insertContact(contact: Contact): Long

    @Query("UPDATE account SET active = NOT active WHERE accountId = :accountId")
    fun toggleAccountActiveStatus(accountId: Long)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM server")
    fun getAllServers() :List<Server>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM account")
    fun getAllAccounts() :List<Account>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM contact")
    fun getAllContacts() :List<Contact>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM server JOIN account ON accountServerId = serverId JOIN contact ON contactServerId = serverId WHERE active = :active")
    fun getContactServerAccount(active: Boolean) :List<ContactServerAccount>

    @Query("SELECT serverId,accountId,contact.* FROM server JOIN account ON accountServerId = serverId JOIN contact ON contactServerId = serverId WHERE active = :active")
    fun getContactServerAccountLimited(active :Boolean) :List<ContactServerAccountLimited>

    @Query("DELETE FROM server")
    fun deleteAllServers() :Int

    @Query("DELETE FROM account")
    fun deleteAllAccounts() :Int
    @Query("DELETE FROM contact")
    fun deleteAllContacts() :Int
}
```

and :-

```
    val allDao = database.allDao();
    allDao.deleteAllContacts()
    allDao.deleteAllAccounts()
    allDao.deleteAllServers()
    currentServer = allDao.insertServer(Server("Server 1"))
    allDao.insertAccount(Account("FRED",currentServer))
    allDao.insertAccount(Account("MARY",currentServer))
    allDao.insertContact(Contact("C1",currentServer))
    currentServer = allDao.insertServer(Server("Server 2"))
    allDao.insertAccount(Account("JANE",currentServer))
    allDao.insertAccount(Account("ANNE",currentServer))
    allDao.insertContact(Contact("C2",currentServer))
    currentServer = allDao.insertServer(Server("Server 3"))
    allDao.insertAccount(Account("VERA",currentServer))
    allDao.insertAccount(Account("JOHN",currentServer))
    allDao.insertContact(Contact("C3",currentServer))
    allDao.insertContact(Contact("C4",currentServer))
    allDao.toggleAccountActiveStatus(1)
    var serverList: List<Server> = allDao.getAllServers()
    for (s: Server in serverList) {
        Log.d("SERVERINFO","Server ID is " + s.serverId + " Name is " + s.servername)
    }

    var accountList = allDao.getAllAccounts()
    for (a: Account in accountList) {
        Log.d("ACCOUNTINFO","Account ID is " + a.accountId +
                " Account Name is " + a.accountName +
                " Account Server ID is " + a.accountServerId +
                " active is " + a.active)
    }

    var contactList = allDao.getAllContacts()
    for (c: Contact in contactList) {
        Log.d("CONTACTINFO","Contact ID is " + c.contactId + " Contact Name is " + c.contactName + " Contact Server ID is " + c.contactServerId)
    }
    val csaList = allDao.getContactServerAccount(true)
    for (c: ContactServerAccount in csaList) {
        Log.d(
            "CSAINFO",
            "SERVER ID is " + c.serverAccount!!.server!!.serverId +
                    " ACCOUNT ID is " + c.serverAccount!!.account!!.accountId +
                    " CONTACT ID is " + c.contact.contactId +
                " CONTACT NAME is " + c.contact.contactName
        )
    }
    val csalList = allDao.getContactServerAccountLimited(true)
    for (c: ContactServerAccountLimited in csalList) {
        Log.d(
            "CSALINFO",
            "SERVER ID is " + c.serverId +
                    " ACCOUNT ID is " + c.accountId +
                    " CONTACT ID is " + c.contact.contactId +
                    " CONTACT NAME is " + c.contact.contactName
        )
    }
}
```

Then the output would be :-

```
2019-10-29 20:56:59.942 D/SERVERINFO: Server ID is 1 Name is Server 1
2019-10-29 20:56:59.943 D/SERVERINFO: Server ID is 2 Name is Server 2
2019-10-29 20:56:59.943 D/SERVERINFO: Server ID is 3 Name is Server 3
2019-10-29 20:56:59.945 D/ACCOUNTINFO: Account ID is 1 Account Name is FRED Account Server ID is 1 active is true
2019-10-29 20:56:59.945 D/ACCOUNTINFO: Account ID is 2 Account Name is MARY Account Server ID is 1 active is false
2019-10-29 20:56:59.945 D/ACCOUNTINFO: Account ID is 3 Account Name is JANE Account Server ID is 2 active is false
2019-10-29 20:56:59.945 D/ACCOUNTINFO: Account ID is 4 Account Name is ANNE Account Server ID is 2 active is false
2019-10-29 20:56:59.945 D/ACCOUNTINFO: Account ID is 5 Account Name is VERA Account Server ID is 3 active is false
2019-10-29 20:56:59.945 D/ACCOUNTINFO: Account ID is 6 Account Name is JOHN Account Server ID is 3 active is false
2019-10-29 20:56:59.947 D/CONTACTINFO: Contact ID is 1 Contact Name is C1 Contact Server ID is 1
2019-10-29 20:56:59.947 D/CONTACTINFO: Contact ID is 2 Contact Name is C2 Contact Server ID is 2
2019-10-29 20:56:59.947 D/CONTACTINFO: Contact ID is 3 Contact Name is C3 Contact Server ID is 3
2019-10-29 20:56:59.947 D/CONTACTINFO: Contact ID is 4 Contact Name is C4 Contact Server ID is 3


2019-10-29 20:56:59.953 D/CSAINFO: SERVER ID is 1 ACCOUNT ID is 2 CONTACT ID is 1 CONTACT NAME is C1
2019-10-29 20:56:59.954 D/CSALINFO: SERVER ID is 1 ACCOUNT ID is 1 CONTACT ID is 1 CONTACT NAME is C1
```

- You may notice that to use the ContactServerAccount POJO used 6ms whilst the ContactServerAccountLimited used 1ms, this could be partly due to the @Relates running queries to build the related objects, whilst with the latter the contact object is built from the core query.
- Additionally the ContractServerAccount has returned account id 2 not 1, this is because account is should really be a list of accounts, which would require a more complex query or subsequent processing to get the active account.

Comment: Well my friend. I really thank you for your time and your concern.
However the problem in the solution u propose is 
 1) I want to have all the columns of each entity (serverDto not serverId, accountDto not accountId)

2) Contact is an accountDto entity and not a different table. The difference between account and contact is tha account.active = 1 and contact.active = 0.

Comment: @james04 There is a problem in your response; the answer clearly states **so something similar to** i.e. it is in-principle not an actual solution. The latter cannot be provided due to the lack of clear information in the question. Such as referring to entities as if those answering are aware of what those entities comprise of and using loose terms such as big objects. If you seek the provision of a code writing service to provide **a solution** then Stack Overflow is not the place, even then such a service would require specifics.